# Simplest PowerShell syntax for using Where-Object on a list of strings

Tags: powershell

If I have a list of people with a "Name" property that's a string I can filter with

`$People | ? Name -Match "Smith"`

But there doesn't seem to be a similarly way to filter a plan list of strings. I have to write a more complex syntax like

`Names | ? {$_ -Match "Smith"}`

Is there a simpler syntax?  It's something I have to do regularly, and I always wonder if there's something I'm missing.

Note: I've simplified a bit far here - I want it to work when it's consuming the output from a function, not just an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that in `Names | ? {$_ -Match "Smith"}` the `Names` is a variable that is an array of strings?

If so, you could use just `Names -Match "Smith"`, like this:

```
$Names = @("Norman McCray", "Kristin Pittman", "Patrick Smith", "John Smith");

$Names -Match "Smith";
```

And the output will be `"Patrick Smith", "John Smith"`, as expected.

#### Update to the comment

##### Names is a function

If `Names` is a function you can force the result to be an array and the syntax above is still valid. Example:

```
function Names { 
  return "Norman McCray", "Kristin Pittman", "Patrick Smith", "John Smith";
}

# Will return all results
Names -Match "Smith";

# Will return filtered values: "Patrick Smith", "John Smith"
@(Names) -Match "Smith";
```

##### Docs

As zett42 sugested in the comment, here's reference:

> The matching operators (-like, -notlike, -match, and -notmatch) find elements that match or do not match a specified pattern.

And

> When the input of these operators is a scalar value, they return a Boolean value. When the input is a collection of values, the operators return any matching members. If there are no matches in a collection, the operators return an empty array.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#matching-operators)

Comment: I suggest to add a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#matching-operators) and/or quote of the reference about comparison operators: _"When the input is a collection of values, the operators return any matching members. If there are no matches in a collection, the operators return an empty array."_

Comment: Yes, but if I'm piping the strings as output from a function then that syntax won't work - sorry I wasn't clearer in the question.
(But thank you, this will be very useful in some situations!)

Comment: @AndrewDucker ok, you can always cast result to the array. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @AndrewDucker Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69927567/edit) your question and add that info in there. Also show what your function outputs, single strings, one at a time or an **array** of strings

Answer (score 0):

A lot of operators work with arrays on the left side.

```
'joe','john','james' -match 'jo'

joe
john
```

Or select-string, although that returns an matchinfo object.  It will convert to string in certain contexts.

```
echo joe john james | select-string jo

joe
john


echo joe john james | select-string jo | % gettype

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    MatchInfo                                System.Object
True     False    MatchInfo                                System.Object
```